# How to automaticallly give input in a tcl script without asking the user

Tags: tcl

I have an instruction:

`delete flash:file`

in my tcl script,  which is to delete a file called `file` from the flash.
It gives the question:

`delete file[confirm]?`

I don't want the user to say `y` or `n`. I just want to delete it, and execute the next instructions.

Is there a way to do so?

EDIT : Okay, so I'm executing a script in a Cisco router console, where `delete flash:<file_name>` is an option which asks the user for confirmation (As shown above). I have included the same in the script.  I am able to delete the file but I have to always press enter for confirmation which I don't want to do. I want it to always confirm the deletion. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: Hard to understand what you are saying without some more code

Comment: `delete` is not a Tcl builtin command. Can you show that code?

Comment: If you don't want user to answer every time, you can use [Expect](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) package to automate it. Whenever it asks to delete file[confirm]? send y.

Comment: You could simply not ask the question…? O_o Until we understand what you're trying to do, you will not get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is a general precautionary to prompt the user for negative operations like file deletion, closure of application and of course router or switch reload.

In that aspect, some applications may provide options to override the prompt and some may not.

In your case, it is obvious that your device will prompt for file deletion. It may be a platform specific. There may be chance that the option to override may available. But not all.

By considering these into account, you could you `send` and `expect` in your script.

A pseudo code can be something like,

```
send "delete flash:file\r"
expect "confirm"
send "y\r"
expect "router#"
```